# Is "much" used in affirmative sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, quantifiers, negative-polarity-items

Is the word "much" used in affirmative sentences?

Example:

> I want to buy much milk.

I know that "much" is used in negative sentences and questions, but I am not sure if using it in affirmative sentences is grammatically correct.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). @Mag: - your version isn't idiomatic, but interestingly, ***Do you** want to buy much milk?* is syntactically normal. More commonly, *I have much money* is non-idiomatic, whereas *Do you have much money?* is perfectly natural.

Comment: While technically correct, no native speaker would use that particular turn of phrase. It's awkward. "Too much milk" and "not much milk" are fine. "I need to buy a lot of milk" would be acceptable.

Comment: see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/191706/much-and-not-much, and, for further reading, https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=much

Comment: @Ricky I would actually use this, but only for the humourous non-standard aspect. That as well as 'much milk needs to be bought' (say for particularly vast quantities). I agree it is not common practice.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Well, yeah, but humor is a whole separate issue, and can't be taught.

Comment: *Much obliged* and *much appreciated* are standard shorthand for Thank you.

Comment: @yosef baskin: Lecture much?

Comment: Answered at [english.stackexchange.com/questions/356827/ {by Greg Lee}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356827/usage-of-not-with-and/356832#356832).

Answer (score 1):

There is more in that question than meets the eye.

*Much* is correct in the affirmative (a large quantity or amount, see [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=much)). It so happens that it is a) slightly archaic b) not often used with concrete words (water, butter, etc.) or ordinary quantities (money). Hence that would sound a little *passé* in normal conversation:

> I bought much milk.

Compared to:

> I bought a lot of milk.

My best guess: *much* still belongs to an educated register and more likely to be used with set phrases:

> I am much obliged.
>
> You will avoid much grief.
>
> He knows much.
>
> Much ado about nothing.

Aside of much + comparative, which also belongs to spoken language:

> It's much better.

By contrast *a lot* is informal and not particularly advisable in written style. One would write:

> A large quantity of water
>
> A large amount of butter

*A lot* did displace *much* but that leaves an awkward gap in formal language, requiring clunky periphrases. Hence I would argue that:

> He bought much milk.

still does have its place in formal style, for brevity. But that would probably be a matter of opinion.

Comment: _Much_ and _many_ are quite frequent in the negative, however. They're not quite NPIs, but _not much_ and _not many_ are more frequent than _not a lot_. The use of _a lot_ has taken over _much_ and _many_'s territory because _a lot (of)_ doesn't require distinguishing between mass and count nouns -- _a lot of money_ and _a lot of people_ both work the same way. It's the affirmative uses that produce questionable sentences, and that's because it's being superseded by _a lot_ and by negative associations.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't included _lotsa_, @John, but I suppose it's mainly used around the London area.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely normal. Oxford English Grammar Course advanced confirms it. Everything that is ok in the formal style, is also ok in the informal. The formal one is more correct and accurate.

Comment: No, it sounds distinctly odd (some might say unacceptably so) in say 'Could I have much rice with my curry, please?'  We'd use 'a lot of' / 'a good helping of'. It's far more normal in negative contexts ('They didn't give us much rice with the curry, did they?')